# Apache Beam in python: How to reuse exactly the same transform on another PCollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Several of my PCollections (that come from different sources) have to be decoded in the same way.

```
hits = (msgs | 'Parse' >> beam.Map(parse)
    | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(decode_hit))
```

Then:

```
dummy_hits = (dummy_msgs | 'Parse' >> beam.Map(parse)
    | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(decode_hit))
```

It would be really nice if I could reuse the transforms thanks to the names I've given them earlier. I naively tried this:

```
dummy_hits = (dummy_msgs | 'Parse'
    | 'Decode')
```

But my pipeline won't build. (TypeError: Expected a PTransform object, got Parse).

I thought it would be possible as documentation for the pipeline module states: "If same transform instance needs to be applied then the right shift operator
  should be used to designate new names (e.g. `input | "label" >> my_tranform`)"

What's the way for doing this? Is this only possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Names have to be unique, but since your sequence of steps is the same maybe you want to create a composite transform like this

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#creating-composite-transforms

So do this:

```
class ParseDecode(beam.PTransform):

  def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (pcoll
            | 'Parse' >> beam.Map(parse)
            | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(decode_hit))
```

So that you can do this:

```
hits = (msgs | 'Parse msgs' >> ParseDecode()
```

and then this:

```
dummy_hits = (dummy_msgs | 'Parse dummy msgs' >> ParseDecode()
```

Comment: In the above code how do we change it such that second transform waits until first transform finishes.

Comment: Pass the output of the first transform into a counter and then pass the output of the counter to the second transform as a side input. And you can have the second transform just ignore the side input

Comment: I am quite new to this and not able to follow what you said. How to pass the output of transform to counter? If possible could you please share the snippet?